# how can I add php code inside a data image using echo

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, youtube, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using my data to get an iframe src, because I'm using this data in my function.js.

for example, with this youtube video :

my custom field with the youtube id :

```
<?php the_sub_field('youtube'); ?>
```

my thumbnail is :

```
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?php the_sub_field('youtube'); ?>/0.jpg" class="photo_medias"/>
```

and my Iframe :

```
<iframe width="706" height="364"  src="//www.youtube.com/embed/<?php the_sub_field('youtube'); ?>?showinfo=0&controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

and when adding this to a img data :

```
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?php the_sub_field('youtube'); ?>/0.jpg"  data-videofull='<iframe width="706" height="364"  src="//www.youtube.com/embed/<?php the_sub_field('youtube'); ?>?showinfo=0&controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>"' class="photo_medias">
```

it works perfectly.

Now I'm trying to generate another data-videofull but with a vimeo code, which is a bit different to generate the thumbnail and to display it

here is my custom field with vimeo id :

```
<?php the_sub_field('vimeo'); ?>
```

my thumbnail is (this is where it's a bit different, I need to use echo inside)

```
<?php echo '<img src="' . get_vimeo_thumb(get_sub_field('vimeo'), 'thumbnail_large') . '"" class="photo_medias" >';?>
```

my iframe (same as for youtube)

```
<iframe width="706" height="364"  src="//player.vimeo.com/video/<?php the_sub_field('vimeo'); ?>?title=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

but when trying to add the iframe adress into data-videofull, I have a php error...

this is what I tried, but it's not working :

```
<?php echo '<img src="' . get_vimeo_thumb(get_sub_field('vimeo'), 'thumbnail_large') . '"" data-videofull='<iframe width="706" height="364"  src="//player.vimeo.com/video/<?php the_sub_field('vimeo'); ?>?title=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>' class="photo_medias" >';?>
```

I guess the problem comes from the echo of my img src but I have to use it...

can anybody help me with this ?

thanks a lot for your help,

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: blank page, I have an error somewhere in my syntax, but I can't find where

Comment: Why two double quotes before data-videofull?

Comment: if you get a white page check your error logs or enable display_errors in your php.ini

Comment: @Fabio I tried without the 2 double quotes, the problem is that I need to use echo again to get the <?php the_sub_field('vimeo'); ?>, but I can't find the correct syntax

Comment: Did you try my code? I had concatenated your functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something wrong, you need to escape single quotes and also don't put php tags inside php other tags but concatenate your strings and functions. Also you have a double double quotes which i removed.

```
<?php echo '<img src="' . get_vimeo_thumb(get_sub_field('vimeo'), 'thumbnail_large') . '" data-videofull=\'<iframe width="706" height="364"  src="//player.vimeo.com/video/'.the_sub_field('vimeo').'?title=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>\' class="photo_medias" >';?>
```

Comment: thanks @Fabio, I add also to replace .the_sub_field('vimeo'). by .get_sub_field('vimeo')., and it works fine

Comment: Perfect dude! I' glad i helped you out!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 

$frame = '<iframe width="706" height="364"  src="//player.vimeo.com/video/'.the_sub_field('vimeo'). '" title=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

echo '<img src="' . get_vimeo_thumb(get_sub_field('vimeo'), 'thumbnail_large') . '" data-videofull="'.$frame.'" class="photo_medias" >';

?>
```